# Worker wsgi. Как с ними работать?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, wsgi, webworkers

Подскажите пожалуйста, какой интерфейс у воркеров в wsgi, не могу найти дельной инфы. Можно статью или что угодно, главное поподробнее.

Comment: Что вообще такое интерфейс у воркеров? Что вы ожидаете получить? Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: У меня есть flask приложение, работает на vps+wsgi+nginx, у меня спавнится пять рабочих, я хочу знать как ими можно управлять (банально изменять количество) и что с ними вообще можно делать

Comment: Это зависит от конкретной реализации конкретного wsgi-сервера и не прописано ни в каких стандартах, читайте справку к вашему wsgi-серверу

Answer (score 0):

Линки на офф доки

Apache

- https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

Общая спецификация

- https://wsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/what.html